# Is it not possible to sort albums by artist on the iPad?

Tags: ipad

So I recently picked up an iPad 2 and promptly loaded all my music onto it. Unfortunately I can't figure out how to have it display my albums grouped by artists like they are on iTunes.  Am I just missing something (probably obvious) or did Apple not bother to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the iPad, you'll have to use the "Artists" tab at the bottom, then tap the desired artist to see their songs grouped by album.

It is silly that they don't let you sort the "Albums" tab by artist.  Hopefully they'll remedy this in the future.

[image]